# How to Add child Elements Dynamically in XML using XSLT with deletion of some child elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT I am trying below operations.I have attahed XMLs

```
i.    Rename Rate_Recurring name to rateAttributeLookup
ii.   Removing Start_Date and Rate child elements from xml
iii.  Converting Bill_Code_New and Inter_Minute_Allowance into new child elements as below
```

But I am facing issue while performing ii operation.
I have nested XML so can you please provide me generic solution for this.
Thanks for your help

Input XML

```
<Package>
    <Rate_Recurring Pattern="SimpleRRate" xsi:type="Voice_Recurring_Rate" ID="3ba5c15b-e347-4af1-875d-809e8443a4c3">
        <Start_Date>2020-04-24</Start_Date>
        <Rate>0</Rate>
        <Bill_Code_New ID="e0a5ddae-3d6b-44ca-90fd-e38ea0c9324b" xsi:type="Lookup_Bill_Code" Pattern="Lookup" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Name>B9999</Name>
        </Bill_Code_New>
        <Inter_Minute_Allowance ID="dfedfdcb-4541-44c0-b0a3-575140fbde05" xsi:type="Lookup_Inter_Minute_Allowance" Pattern="Lookup" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Name>Unlimited</Name>
        </Inter_Minute_Allowance>
        <Bill_Code>B9999</Bill_Code>
    </Rate_Recurring>

</Package>
```

Output XML

```
<Package>
   <rateAttributeLookup>
      <element>
         <elementName>Bill_Code_New</elementName>
         <rateAttributeId>e0a5ddae-3d6b-44ca-90fd-e38ea0c9324b</rateAttributeId>
      </element>
      <element>
         <elementName>Inter_Minute_Allowance</elementName>
         <rateAttributeId>dfedfdcb-4541-44c0-b0a3-575140fbde05</rateAttributeId>
      </element>
   </rateAttributeLookup>
</Package>
```

XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[@Pattern = 'SimpleNRRate'  or @Pattern = 'SimpleRRate'] ">
        <rateAttributeLookup>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:if test="@ID">
                    <elementName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    </elementName>
                    <rateAttributeId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                    </rateAttributeId>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </rateAttributeLookup>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The input you show is not well-formed XML document and will produce an error: it uses the `xsi` prefix without binding it to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rate_Recurring">
    <rateAttributeLookup>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </rateAttributeLookup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Bill_Code_New | Inter_Minute_Allowance">
    <element>
        <elementName>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </elementName>
        <rateAttributeId>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        </rateAttributeId>
    </element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Start_Date | Rate"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
Sorry but we cannot hard code the line 
<xsl:template match="Bill_Code_New | Inter_Minute_Allowance">
Is there any other way we can do that?
Can we use nested template match?

Comment: 1. Templates cannot be nested. 2. In your question you say: *"iii.  Converting Bill_Code_New and Inter_Minute_Allowance into new child elements"*-  IOW, you name the elements explicitly. If it's not possible to match/select these by their names, then provide another criteria to identify them.